# mErrCount: Identifier not found although it is declared in the include path of Project properties

Tags: c++

This is my code named **test.cpp**

```
#include <test.h>

namespace ScStdTb {

#define CFG_REG 0
#define CMD_REG 0x4
#define CTRL_REG 0x8
#define STAT_REG 0xC

void BasicTB::test()
{
        void testCase();
        
}

void testCase()
{
     unsigned int data = 0x0;
     data=1;
     REG_WRITE(CTRL_REG,&data);

}

}
```

REG_WRITE is a macro defined in TbCommBase.h

Here is the code snippet from that:

```
/*macro for register read/write*/
#define REG_WRITE(reg, value) \
    if (send_transaction((reg), value, B_WR)) {\
        mErrCount++;\
        PRINT_DBG("Write failed : Reg at 0x"<< hex << (reg)\
                <<", data 0x"<< value << dec);\
    } else {\
        wait_delta();\
    }
```

In the project properties I have added the path to **TbCommBase.h** under
Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories.

Also mErrCount is defined in **TbCommBase.h**

```
unsigned int                  mErrCount;
```

When I try to compile **test.cpp** I get the following errors:

> error C2065: 'mErrCount' : undeclared identifier
>
> error C3861: 'send_transaction': identifier not found
>
> error C3861: 'name': identifier not found
>
> error C3861: 'wait_delta': identifier not found

There is no error in the file **TbCommBase.h** as such. It only shows undeclared identifier only in **test.cpp** although I have referenced to the header. I have executed a previous file similarly without any issues.

Any ideas ?

Comment: perhaps you need to include `TbCommBase.h`. why not write a proper function instead of this long macro???

Comment: and where `mErrCount` is defined?

Comment: mErrCount is defined in the header file itself.  Its already existing and is used by many files. So I cannot write it as a separate function.

Comment: @Azad is right. You need to include the following line `#include "TbCommBase.h"` in your `test.cpp`

Comment: has `TbCommBase.h` included in `test.h` if not you should include it in `test.cpp`

Comment: I tried adding the same but without success. As I said I have executed a similar module under similar circumstances and it worked. I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was pretty simple. The **scope resolution operator** caused the problem.

Here is the updated code.

```
#include <ifxPkcTest.h>
namespace ScStdTb {

#define CFG_REG 0
#define CMD_REG 0x4
#define CTRL_REG 0x8
#define STAT_REG 0xC

void BasicTB::test()
{
        void testCase();

}

void BasicTB::testCase()              //SOLUTION
{
     unsigned int data = 0x0;
     data=1;
     REG_WRITE(CTRL_REG,&data);

}

}
```